# New thread inside doInBackground: Will it impact the performance?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, file, android-asynctask

If I start a new thread inside `doInBackground` method of `AsyncTask`, will it be okay from performance point of view?
I've written a small program which downloads a file from a server. The method runs inside `doInBackground`. Now, in order to find out the current size of downloaded file, I start a new thread which reads the number of bytes being piped to local `File` object. I need this to publish the percentage of download. Here is the code snippet:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        client.download(dir + "/" + component0, new java.io.File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + component0));
        Thread trd = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (tempfile.length() != filesize) {
                    if (tempfile.length() * 100 / filesize != percent) {
                        percent = (int) (tempfile.length() * 100 / filesize);
                        publishProgress(percent);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        trd.start();

    } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException
            | FTPIllegalReplyException | FTPException
            | FTPDataTransferException | FTPAbortedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The program works fine but it seems like the download speed is a bit slower than it should be. Has it something to do with the new `Thread` being created inside the `doInBackground` method?

Comment: You know that starting another thread inside doinbackground doesn't make sense?

Comment: I understand that, but unfortunately, I don't have any means to know the file size at local device. My question is, will it impact the performance of doInBackground?

Comment: Instead of checking the filesize, why not count the number bytes downloaded, if this is feasible ? And no, it won't make a performance difference, provided you don't run the second thread _too_ often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that, I think it wont impact the performance in the way the user can tell, but it is just bad practice. instead using the Handler class function postDelay which describe here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)

you can delay the function call to X seconds and call it again each time untill the download completes:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
void doWork() {
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do work here...
                if (!finish) {
                    doWork();
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
}
```